# How do I pass a value of a dropdown as a parameter in jquery datatables ajax?

Tags: mvc.jquery.datatables

i have a dropdown in mvc view- where the value that is selected is to be sent as a paramater in the ajax call of jquery datatables. I am not sure what the right syntax is. Here is snippet my currrent code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("StatusType", "Select a Value")
    </p>
    <p>
        Find by Keyword or Phrase in Heading Or Description: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>

}
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblsr')) {
            $('#tblsr').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#tblsr').dataTable().empty();

        }

        var complete = $('#tblsr').DataTable(
            {
                "serverSide": true,
                "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "ajax":
                    {
                        url: "/ServiceRequests/SRList",
                        method: "POST",
                        "data": { "StatusType": StatusType}
                    },
```

What is the appropriate syntax for the line under method: POST? If I hardcode in "Open" or "closed' instead of StatusType, the datatables does filter properly, so the value is properly passed, so I just dont know what the appropriate syntax to refer to the dropdown value...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

figured it out :

```
 var complete = $('#tblsr').DataTable(
            {

                "serverSide": true,
                "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "ajax":
                    {
                        url: "/ServiceRequests/SRList",
                        method: "POST",
                        "data":  {
                            "StatusType": $("#StatusType").val()
                           //"StatusType": "Open"

                        }

                    },
```